# How to allow HTTP-connections (not HTTPS) in WebView on Android?

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I have a `WebView` application on Android and I want to fetch data from a resource which uses `HTTP` only. To do so, I use `XMLHttpRequest` API in JavaScript.

When I fetch data from any other `HTTPS-resource`, everything is OK. But `HTTP` never works. How can I fix that?

Is there any way to allow `HTTP-connections` using `JavaScript`?

Comment: can you show the code you're using for the `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: Do you get any error message? Did you try to set `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the application tag in the Android manifest?

Comment: Thank you @dthulke! I did not know about this attribute. HTTP works now, too.

Answer (score 11):

`android:usesCleartextTraffic`The default value for apps that target API level 27 or lower is `true`. Apps that target API level 28 or higher default to `false`. [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <application
     ...
     android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
     ...>
     ...
   </application>
</manifest>
```