# Android WebView is converting the http request to https

Tags: android, kotlin, http, https, webview

I am trying to load a webview with the content from an Http andpoint but the webview is automatically converting the url to https and giving following error.

The webpage could not be loaded because: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I am already using android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in manifest file

Please help me in overcoming this issue.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56837613/13598222

Comment: I am already using  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in manifest file

Comment: Does the endpoint work in a web browser? Or is the server rewriting the request as https (possibly with a bad certificate)? You might want to take a look at this too: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-network-security-config#0 it covers a few different aspects of security configuration and the different options you have

Comment: I haven't seen a page redirect to https, but I do know that `webView.settings.safeBrowsingEnabled` needs to be set to false in order to disable safe (https) browsing.